# How to remove specific text from a cell

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

So for example, in cell A1 I might have "Assistant to the Regional Manager." My original idea was to use Instr like this:

```
If InStr(1, Cells(x, 1).Value, "Assistant") > 0 Then
        Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value - "Assistant to the "
```

so that only "Regional Manager" remains, but this does not work. Is there a way to remove "Assistant to the "?

Comment: Combine it with `mid()`

Comment: I am curious as to why VBA? You can achieve these using Excel formulas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
Cells(x, 1).Value = Replace(Cells(x, 1).Value, "Assistant to the ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve what you want

1. `Replace`: FoxInCloud has already covered that. **<==This is the easiest**.
2. `Split`:

   ```
   Debug.Print Split(Cells(x, 1).Value,"Assistant to the ")(1)
   ```
3. `Mid/Len`:

   ```
   Debug.Print Mid(Cells(x, 1).Value, Len("Assistant to the ") + 1, _
   Len(Cells(x, 1).Value) - Len("Assistant to the "))
   ```
4. `Right/Len`:

   ```
   Debug.Print Right(Cells(x, 1).Value, Len("Assistant to the "))
   ```

I would highly recommend that you spend some time studying how these functions work to get a better idea.